# NoMethodError in Browse#home

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, rails-activerecord

I have the following view file in browse/home

```
<% if current_user %>
<% @post = Post.new %>
<%=render :partial => 'posts/newpost.html.erb'%>
<div id="postsfeed">
<%= render :partial => 'post.html.erb', :locals => { :posts_streams => @posts_streams } %>
</div></br>
<% end %>
```

posts/newpost.html.erb is

```
<%= form_for(@post) do |f| %>
<div class="fields">
<%= f.label "Post" %><br />
<%= f.text_field :post %>
</div>
<div class="actions" id="refreshposts">
<%= f.submit("Post") %>
</div>
<% end %>
```

models/post.rb is as follows

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
attr_accessible :post, :posted_by, :posted_by_uid
end
```

logs:

```
Rendered browse/home.html.erb within layouts/application (42.9ms)
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 72ms

ActionView::Template::Error (undefined method `post' for #<Post:0x00000003ad7cf0>):
1: <%= form_for(@post) do |f| %>
2: <div class="fields">
3:     <%= f.label "Post" %><br />
4:     <%= f.text_field :post %>
5:   </div>
6: <div class="actions" id="refreshposts">
7:     <%= f.submit("Post") %>
app/views/posts/_newpost.html.erb:4:in `block in _app_views_posts__newpost_html_erb__281623928071728826_30583780'
app/views/posts/_newpost.html.erb:1:in `_app_views_posts__newpost_html_erb__281623928071728826_30583780'
app/views/browse/home.html.erb:3:in `_app_views_browse_home_html_erb___3611275753955382446_40484320'
```

when I initiate the server. It returns  NoMethodError in Browse#home. Please suggest a way to resolve this

Thank you

Comment: Give the full error stack.

Comment: @ArupRakshit updated the q with the logs

Comment: Post your controller code

Comment: What attributes does your Post model have? It likely doesn't have a `post` attribute, which is why it's erroring.

Comment: @sevenseacat I forgot to run rake db:migrate to update my posts attributes in the db. It works now Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably, there should be a **post column** in posts table in database

Also following points should be noted as per [Rails standards](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html#Using Partials):

Avoid to mention extension .html.erb, So change the code from:

```
<%= render :partial => 'posts/newpost.html.erb'%> 

<%= render :partial => 'post.html.erb', :locals => { :posts_streams => @posts_streams } %>
```

to:

```
<%= render :partial => 'posts/newpost'%> 

<%= render :partial => 'post', :locals => { :posts_streams => @posts_streams } %>
```

Also the partial begins with an underscore, so place partial in views folder as posts/_newpost.html.erb.

Comment: But with referring as `:partial` no `underscore` should be prefixed.

Comment: It's written **posts/newpost.html.erb is** just above the reference of **newpost** partial file which should be **posts/_newpost.html.erb is**

Comment: No,it should be just `<%=render :partial => 'posts/newpost'%>`

Comment: Yes this is correct but I was referring to line above the partial file description within the question, which leads to think probably partial is introduced in wrong format. Thanks

Comment: Yes,try adding it your answer.

Comment: changing it to `attr_accessor` will make the error go away, but will fix nothing.

Comment: the only part of this answer that actually relates to the question is the first line.

Answer (score -1):

check your routes and add

```
 resources posts
```

or to add partial take example your file is '_partial.html.erb'

```
   <%= render controller/partial %>
```

template error is the error which tells you that there is no such page you are rendering to, so do check whether it exists to the same path or not.